# Handling repeating tasks in Python

Tags: python, multithreading

Hi guys I'm new to Python and I can't find any approaches to my scenario . How can I start multiple repetitive tasks of the same function, with different parameters, and still have the ability to stop a certain one?

To make things clearer check the image bellow. I have an f(x) function. I want to start multiple independent recurring calls, with different entry data and at a later time stop them separately as well.

[description http://happyfacedevs.com/public/python.png](http://happyfacedevs.com/public/python.png)

**UPDATE:** Here's the whole scenario. I have a main function that gets called every 60 secs. This function gets a list of urls and based on some conditions it decides to start  the repeating function with the given url or stops an already running one.

```
def f(x):
    #repeat every 5 secs until stopped
    #do stuff with x


def mainTask():
    #gets a new list of urls

    #for every url, start a new repeating task or stop an existing one
    #based on some conditions

    threading.Timer(60, mainTask).start()


mainTask()
```

Comment: Can you clarify "multiple repetitive tasks?"  Do you mean that you want to call `f(a)`, `f(b)`, `f(c)` once each and have them run repeatedly until cancelled, or do you simply mean that you want to call `f(a)`, `f(b)`, `f(c)` and be able to stop any one of them at a later time?

Comment: To run things in parallel you can use Multiprocessing, or Multithreading. For repetitive tasks you need to loop (like a while loop) in order to be able to cancel them, you need a loop running on the main which will check for user stop command, which will notify the loops running on the functions to exit. These are 3 distinct different questions. Please ask a new question for each one, defining what you have tried, and what your goals are, include as much information/data as you can.

Comment: @sberry call every f(x) once and then have them recall themselves until stoped. There can be multiple (or even none) tasks running at a certain point in time. The 3 ones were only an example.

Answer (score 2):

you can use gevent.spawn() to implement your independent tasks. a snippet from http://www.gevent.org/intro.html#example

```
>>>import gevent
>>>from gevent import socket
>>>urls = ['www.google.com', 'www.example.com', 'www.python.org']
>>>jobs = [gevent.spawn(socket.gethostbyname, url) for url in urls]
>>>gevent.joinall(jobs, timeout=2)
>>>[job.value for job in jobs]
['74.125.79.106', '208.77.188.166', '82.94.164.162']
```

Answer (score 0):

If `a,b,c` is constant all time:

```
import time
import threading

def f(param, stop_event):
    while not stop_event.is_set():
         # do something with param


events = {'a': threading.Event(), 
          'b': threading.Event(), 
          'c': threading.Event(), 
}
for param, ev in zip([a, b, c], events):
    t = Thread(target=f, args=(param, ev))
    t.start()
time.sleep(10)
events['a'].set() # stop a
time.sleep(10)
events['b'].set() # stop b
time.sleep(10)
events['c'].set() # stop c
```

If `a,b,c` new in iteration you can use `Queue`:

```
import time
import threading

def f(q, stop_event):
    while not stop_event.is_set():
         param = q.get()
         # do something with param

q = threading.Queue()
events = {'a': threading.Event(), 
          'b': threading.Event(), 
          'c': threading.Event(), 
}
for ev in events:
    t = Thread(target=f, args=(q, ev))
    t.start()
q.put(a)
q.put(b)
q.put(c)
time.sleep(10)
events['a'].set() # stop a
time.sleep(10)
events['b'].set() # stop b
time.sleep(10)
events['c'].set() # stop c
```

This is some sample solutions.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very (too) broad question without showing any specific examples and there are many ways to achieve what you want.  However, it might be worth looking at [PEP 3156](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3156/) and [tulip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tulip) for a high-level solution.